# Exception not caught when using BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have a WPF window with a  `BackgroundWorker`. I get an exception in `Send()` method here:

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     smtpClient.Send(mail);
}
```

which in turn is invoked in a `Click` Event for some button like this:

```
private async void SendClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (MessageServiceClient client = new MessageServiceClient())
    {
        try
        {
            [...]
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error! Check your sender data!", "!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            [...]
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this exception doesn't get handled? When I was doing it not asynchronously (everything was in `SendClickAsync()` method) the message box popped up nicely.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you call `worker.RunWorkerAsync()` method, your main thread continue execution and exits try..catch block. To handle exception use `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler. `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` arguement has property `Error` which will contain exception object:

```
void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Error", "!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
       return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just realised my edit might not be good, because I am using Winforms and OP is using WPF. If that's the case, please ignore my effort to adjust your answer!

Comment: @Wilson please propose your edit as a comment here.

Answer (score 3):

The `BackgroundWorker` is using thread pool threads, so it doesn't want your code to be able to do something weird on the worker thread. That's why the `BackgroundWorker` swallows your exception that happened during `DoWork` and lets you know that it happened through `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Error`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the exception is not handled is because it is thrown on a different thread.
The call to `worker.RunWorkerAsync();` does not block, rather it starts the job on the threadpool and returns control immediately in the main thread - this is the whole point to doing it asynchronously.

But this also means that after the call to `worker.RunWorkerAsync()` the main thread exits your try-catch block, so the exception doesn't get handled (on your main thread).